# Linux Mint 12: DVD version vs CD version

Tags: linux-mint

I have the CD version so why should i consider upgrading to the DVD version? what are the major features that the DVD version offer? From a programmer's point of view:

- performance
- Libraries
- additional software

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need to upgrade, since you can install everything that the DVD version has. Usually those DVD versions are provided only for convenience (e.g. people installing on systems with slow internet connections).

Namely, from Mint's [download page](http://www.linuxmint.com/download.php):

> A version which fits on a CD, without multimedia support and extra
>   applications. For magazines, companies and distributors in the USA,
>   Japan and countries where the legislation allows patents to apply to
>   software and distribution of restricted technologies may require the
>   acquisition of 3rd party licenses*.